# Circle of Apollonius; proving a tangent line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

Quick recap, since there are several circles of Apollonius:

> Given a triangle with fixed base and the other two sides in known ratio, [the circle of Apollonius (of the first type)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius%27_definition_of_a_circle) gives the possible positions of the third point.

Now constructing that circle from the two base points $A$ and $B$ and another point $D$ that divides $AB$ in the appropriate ratio is a question considered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328836), which can be achieved in various different ways. $D$ is clearly on the Apollonian circle,  so finding one more point and knowing that the center of the circle $O$ is on $AB$ is sufficient to construct it.

The construction I gave is this:

> Construct the circle $\color{#0B2}{\Gamma}$ centred on $D$ through the nearer of $A$ and $B$, which I will assume is point $B$. Also construct a line perpendicular to $AB$ at $B$. Then form the tangent to circle $\color{#0B2}{\Gamma}$ from $A$. This intersects the perpendicular at $E$, which is on the Apollonius circle because $\triangle AEB$ is similar to the right triangle $\triangle ADT$ (with $T$ the tangent point of $A$ on $\color{#0B2}{\Gamma}$), so $|AE|:|EB| = |AD|:|DT| = |AD|:|BD|$ as required.

[image]

Now the extra claim I make - visible in the diagram - is that $AE$ is a tangent to the Apollonius circle. I initially thought I had proved this via the power of point $A$ to the circle with a bit of Pythagoras, but I don't really think this works. However I do think that $AE$ is actually tangent and certainly this reliably works in interactive geometry tools.

So my question is: **can you prove (or disprove) that $AE$ is tangent to the circle of Apollonius shown?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $|AE|:|EB| = |AD|:|BD|$, $DE$ is angle bisector of $\angle AEB$.

Then $$\angle BEO = \angle DEO - \angle DEB=\angle ODE - \angle AED=\angle EAB$$

This implies $OE$ is tangent to circumcircle of $\triangle ABE$. But $ABE$ is a right triangle with its circumcenter on $AE$. So $OE \perp AE$ which means $AE$ is tangent to the Apollonian circle $(O)$.

Comment: Nice, and also $\angle BEO = \angle EAB$ gives $\angle AEO = \angle AEB +  \angle EAB  =\perp$ immediately

Comment: Oh that is true. Missed the simple way :)